# Why does my github desktop 'sync' button end in a pull request instead of a push?

Tags: github, pull-request, github-for-windows

After cloning a repository using the 'open in desktop' button on github, if I make changes to the repo, commit those changes and click 'sync', it pulls but doesn't push. It creates a pull request. Which I can then approve in the website interface.

I didn't expect that - I would expect it to push. Hovering the sync button says 'pull and push'. What could be wrong ?

If this is default behaviour, is there a way to get the Github Desktop app to really really push ?

Comment: I think this is by design to keep things easier (only sync and PR), and to encourage using pull requests.

Comment: @Julian  - if I read the docs and other QA here in SO, they all talk about sync 'pushing changes' as if it really pushes. Did it perhaps recently change ?

Comment: updated the question, adding if there is way to turn that 'feature' OFF :-)